# Package eRm-LR test error

Tags: r

I am working my way through package eRm for Rasch analysis, in particular to fit Partial Credit Model, since my response is polychotomous. I am struggling with DIF analysis, because of an error with LR test. Could someone please help? What does this mean? How can I define a factor for splitcr?

```
Error in LRtest.Rm(x, splitcr = G, se = TRUE): 
No items with appropriate response patterns left to perform LR-test!
```

Comment: Please share some sample data that you are using for analysis. Please share the output of `dput(head(data.frame))` in the question description along with some description of the variables in the data.frame.

Comment: I am not able to explain you exactly the reason for the error 
 but withtin this [script](http://statmath.wu-wien.ac.at/~hatz/psychometrics/10w/RM_handouts_7.pdf) you might find a starting point. The data used in the script are [here](http://statmath.wu.ac.at/~hatz/psychometrics/10w/).